# Simple data inserting using Mysqli

Tags: php

[This is the HTML code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CMRZt.png)

[This is the sql page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VYtZy.png)

[This is the database page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L2px0.png)

[This is the Output Page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IG7UX.png)

**Why phn is not inserted to the database??**

Comment: Images of code are absolutely useless, as are pictures of your entire desktop. See [this Meta post](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/62576) for a list of the many reasons why you should avoid posting images. Code and errors are in text, and should be posted as such. When you created your account here, it was suggested you take the [tour] and read the [help] pages in order to familiarize yourself with this site. Please do so, especially [ask] and [mcve], before posting your next question here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
error_reporting(0);
```

This code will work for your issue.

The way you post your code is not good BTW.

Answer (score 0):

Please share full page screenshot of 'process.php' page.

I will edit my answer once you upload your file.

FYI : its a notice error, so you can ignore it by using following command on the top of your file 'process.php'

```
error_reporting(0);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help.